# Advanced datagridview Cell formatting is not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using advanced datagridview for my form 2 and I have set the defaultcellstyle value is 'MM/dd/yyyy'. for the first load, it is working fine but next time again I am loading form 2 it is not supporting the formatting. it is showing 09/01/2020 12:00:00 AM and I don't want this format. I only want the 'MM/dd/yyyy' format for my 5th column. Please advise, I am stuck with this

Here is the code:

```
public Form2(DataTable dt, string LoginName) {
  InitializeComponent();
  lblLoginName.Text = LoginName;
  bindingsource1.DataSource = dt;
  advancedDataGridView1.DataSource=bindingsource1;
  advancedDataGridView1.Columns["CreatedOn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by… _”but next time again I am loading form 2”_ ? So, the code creates a “new” form2, fires its “load” event and the formatting is correct. Then, later, you create another “new” form2, fires its “load” event and the formatting is not used? I “advise” you to show an example of this. Otherwise, speculation and back and forth questions are going to be the fare. One point, if you are using a data source to the grid and switch the data source… you will need to re-define the formatting.

Comment: On form 2 Load I am using this line so make sure "CreatedOn" columns default cell style format is 'MM/dd/yyyy'.         advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = dt; advancedDataGridView1.Columns["CreatedOn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";  I can switch between the form 1 and form 2.

Comment: On form 1, when I click on the Data button I am passing the data table on form 2 and binding with form 2 advanced datagridview. Now I am coming back on form 1 using FormView Button. After that, now I am clicking on the 'Data' button and passing data table on form2 it is not displaying the correct formatting for "CreatedOn" column.

Comment: Without seeing the code… I am simply saying that when the line of code executes…  `advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` THEN, you need to redefine the column format. If you do not want to redefine the column each time the data source changes, then I suggest manually adding the column (in code or the designer) to the “grid”, format it as you want, then use its `DataPropertyName` to mate it to the proper column in the `DataTable`.

Comment: Added the code in the question.

Comment: The posted code appears to work as expected… there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I always use `DataBidingComplete` event for my `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void grvCalendar_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
            colPlanDate.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

`colPlanDate` is the name of the column, not `headertext`

I have to bind and rebind `Datasource` many times so with this, after each binding or reloading, it will repaint the format for datetime value.

This event handler is also useful when you want to format your cells, such as text color or changing images.

Comment: I tried and it is not working but I found the different solution to fix this.

Comment: I formatted the date format in the stored procedure and the same formatting applied on datagridview columns in code. This solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, formatting in sql in advance will solve this specific datetime issue. I have not tested but the code binds the ```datatable``` to a ```bindingsoure``` before binding to ```datasource``` of gridview may not trigger ```databindingcomplete```, but I still doubt it. I think it should work even in this case. To try this ```event``` as an alternative, try binding ```datatable``` directly to gridview ```datasource```. For example: ```advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = dt```. This is my doing when dealing with gridview